# How to change a UIBarButtonItem in a UINavigationBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

I'm trying to set up a list of items that can be edited. I have a main view, with a UINavigationBar at the top and a UITableView directly under it. I'd like to have my "edit" button change to a "done" button on click, but I can't figure out how to do it.

If I could do it in the code (not it interface builder), I could just replace it, but I can't even do that. I've seen some code using [self.navigationItem], but in my case self is a UIView.

It also feels a bit odd to be using a UINavigationBar when I don't want navigation (this is one page only), but I want a toolbar with a title and and a button, so I don't think really have a choice.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I create one button that can change from Edit to Done. It's a tip from More iPhone Development book.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIBarButtonItem *editButton = self.editButtonItem;  
    [editButton setTarget:self]; 
    [editButton setAction:@selector(toggleEdit)]; 
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = editButton; 
}
```

And the method toggleEdit

```
- (IBAction)toggleEdit { 
    BOOL editing = !self.tableView.editing; 
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = !editing; 
    if (editing) {
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Done", @"Done");
        //Added in the edition for this button has the same color of the UIBarButtonSystemItemDone
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleDone;
    } else {
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Edit", @"Edit"); 
        //Added in the edition for this button has the same color of the UIBarButtonSystemItemDone
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.style = UIBarButtonItemStylePlain;
    }
    [self.tableView setEditing:editing animated:YES]; 
}
```

Then you don't need replace any of them.

Comment: Ah, yeah, that looks good. Though, I don't think you get that nice "Done" style that way, where the button is a slightly different color.

Comment: Now with the change of the style, the button DONE of this code is exactly equal to UIBarButtonSystemItemDone.

Answer (score 4):

When you use `self.editButtonItem`, you don't need to change the style and text of the button, it is done automatically.  Try removing that code, it will still work :)

Answer (score 2):

set up nav button in IB with the following linked in IB and create an outlet called editOutlet and and an action called editToggle in your header file and your method is as easy as this:

```
-(IBAction) editToggle:(id) sender {

if (self.tableViewOutlet.isEditing == NO) {

    self.editOutlet.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Done", @"Done");
    self.editOutlet.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleDone;
    [self.tableViewOutlet setEditing:YES animated:YES];

}else {
    self.editOutlet.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Edit", @"Edit"); 
    self.editOutlet.style = UIBarButtonItemStylePlain;
    [self.tableViewOutlet setEditing:NO animated:YES];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it! Looks like you can get to the UINavigationItem by using the topItem property. Just had to read through the docs, like always!

Answer (score 0):

you can try it

```
[self setValue:viewController.navigationItem forKey:@"_navigationItem"];
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
```